# Using Express Js, I need submit button to redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a journal entry input text and once the user clicks "submit", the page should be redirected to show them their entry.

Answer (score 1):

Express.js has 2 parts of a request. The **request** and the **response**. The submit button should be part of a form that submits a request. You decide what to do with the request body in Express.js, and you send a response. You can send a status code, or, in your case, a redirect.

In your server-side post function, you'll want to make sure you include

```
res.redirect(307, 'url');
```

The **307** refers to the HTTP status code of "temporary redirect" and **url** refers to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

You’re just going to have to make a get request from your front end on success of submission. All express will be doing in your case will be serving the requests. This is front end logic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).